# What is the difference between these three delegate declarations?

Tags: c#, delegates

Assume there is the following delegate:

```
delegate int Foo(int x);
```

I've seen people create this delegate in multiple ways, for example:

**Example 1:**

```
Foo f = Bar;
```

With *Bar* being:

```
int Bar(int x) => x * 2;
```

**Example 2:**

```
Foo f = new Foo(x => x * 2);
```

**Example 3:**

```
Foo f = x => x * 2;
```

Are there any differences (pro's, con's, efficiency, etc.) other than personal coding style preference?

Comment: See [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

Comment: Perhaps if I reword the question to be more about the MSIL code that is being generated it'd seem less opinion based.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What *is* this difference you refer to?

Comment: @Timmeh If you just want to see the MSIL code generated, then compile the code, rather than asking other people to compile your code for you.

Comment: @Servy You're right, although I didn't expect all 3 to produce the same MSIL, and since I've never read MSIL code I don't think the difference (if there is any) would've been of as much use to me as compared to some of the experts on here.

Comment: @Timmeh So then you *don't* want to know the difference between the IL code.  If you just want to know the high level differences, all you had to do was do a simple google search and look at any of the tens of thousands of resources out there with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although examples 2 and 3 are pretty much identical, the two may become different from example 1 when used as local declarations.

There is no difference between 2 and 3: in 2, you specify delegate type explicitly, while in the second case you let the compiler figure out the type of the delegate by looking at the type of `f`. When `f` is a local variable, you can further simplify the declaration to

```
var f = new Foo(x => x * 2);
```

so that `Foo` is specified only once.

The first example uses a lambda-bodied method to define a delegate through a method group. The obvious difference here is that this way of declaring a delegate requires a separate method.

However, there is another subtle difference here: when delegates from examples 2 and 3 are used in a local context, they can close over local variables. In contrast, example 1 cannot capture local variables, even if you use it in a local context.

Code examples 2 and 3 let you do this:

```
Foo Make(int y) {
    var res = x => x * y; // y is captured from the context
    return res;
}
```

while example 1 is limited to using `x` that you pass and any fields of the object that declares `Bar`.

Therefore, you need to consider these points when deciding among these three options:

- If you need a delegate that does not close over local variables, and relies on logic that can be used elsewhere, use method group,
- If you need a delegate that closes over local variables, use 2 with `var`, or 3,
- If you are declaring a field, use 3, because you must specify the type of the field anyway.

Comment: As you stated with var (but also with for example anonymous objects) you cannot use method 3 without casting it explicitly (`(Foo)(x => x * 2)`), it would seem to me that this would require an extra operation. So I guess method 2 would be better than method 3 in some occasions?

Comment: @Timmeh `Foo(x => x * 2)` is definitely better than `((Foo)(x => x * 2))`. Method 3 is fine in the context of a field declaration (as opposed to a local declaration) because you must specify the type explicitly, i.e. there's no option to use `var`.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that in Example 1 you can reuse your function Bar.  I believe that 2 and 3 are synonymous and that the lambda expression is just syntactic sugar for the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

The first, example below is called `expression bodied method`, so the delegate will refer to this method which returns an `int` and will take whatever value of `x` is and multiply it by `2`.

```
int Bar(int x) => x * 2;
```

The second, example below is using a `lambda expression`, it is instantiating the delegate and passing a reference to the method that will return the value of `x` multiplied by `2`.

```
Foo f = new Foo(x => x * 2);
```

The last example is just syntactic sugar which behind the scenes is pretty much the same as the example above.

```
Foo f = x => x * 2;
```

> Are there any differences (pro's, con's, efficiency, etc.) other than
>   personal coding style preference?

they all essentially accomplish the same end result, however, the first example you could reuse the method as many times as you want whereas the last two you're passing in a behaviour that just gets executed (at a later time) without any identifier to the method for later reuse.